# Enabling Asynchronous IO at HP-UX Operating System

Tags: io, hp-ux, async

We are using HP-UX Itanium version B.11.31 and this server is used for running Sybase database version ASE15.7. I would like to know how to enable Asynchronous IO at Operating System level.

I went through Sybase ASE and their suggestion is provided at this [link](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc35823.1572/doc/html/san1334282773953.html).

[image: Sybase Asynchronous IO]

Appreciate your valuable input as which one should be chosen. I feel it should be "Enabling Asynchronous I/O for File System Devices."

Database is stored in the file system and they are VxFS(Veritas File System)

Comment: What are the plans for storing the database? On raw disks or in filesystems?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Database storage is file system and not raw devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the three pages are somewhat poorly titled.

"Enabling Asynchronous Disk I/O HP-UX" page describes the installation of the asynchronous I/O driver. It would be definitely needed if you wanted to use asynchronous I/O with raw devices, but you aren't planning to do that.

I found [this link](https://community.hpe.com/hpeb/attachments/hpeb/itrc-156/57308/1/10410.htm) to an old HP Knowledge Mine document that confirms that the `asyncdisk` driver is for raw disk access only.

"Enabling Asynchronous I/O for File System Devices" page describes a pair of HP-UX kernel tunables as a prerequisite, but the actual task seems to be *how to enable Sybase to **use** HP-UX asynchronous file I/O*, assuming it's available.

"Enabling Asynchronous I/O for File Systems" page describes how to make sure HP-UX can **provide** asynchronous file I/O. It says "you need to have OnlineJFS installed". Basically, this page should have been a part of the "prerequisites" section of the previous page.

Comment: I checked with Sysadmin and seems 3rd option i.e. changes pertaining to VxFS is already there at server. so, if I got your point correctly, it should be change only for 2nd point i.e. change pertaining to kctune.

Comment: Exactly. I don't really see why Sybase has separated the 2nd and 3rd points, as they clearly belong together.